# PWA venia theme URL not working in browser

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa, pwa-studio

I am trying to install a new instance of pwa with Magento 2.3.1
I am using Magento's cloud setup URL provided by default in my `.env` file. I get my build successful and the URLs are generated correctly but could not open the link in browser. It hangs at "Loading Homepage content..." text.
I could see below error repeatedly thrown in my browser console.

> react-dom.development.js?e595:506 Warning: Encountered two children
>   with the same key, 'ReferenceError13H'. Keys should be unique so that
>   components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may
>   cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is
>   unsupported and could change in a future version.

I have checked with multiple install of Magento as well as `pwa-studio` with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's browser compatibility issue. 
Please try to check it in different browsers, also please update your current browser.

Comment: Thanks Saphal, it was indeed browser issue. Venia theme does not seem to work with Chromium 65

Comment: ahh, great :) :)

Comment: Thanks Saphal, your solutions seems good!

Comment: Not working in any browser.